# Scheme, search if a word is a part of list

Tags: list, scheme

I did a program which is searching if an element is a part of the list, but it is not working with words
My program:

```
(define (element? xs lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) #f) 
        ((eq? xs (car lst)) #t) 
        (#t (element? x (cdr lst)))))
```

examples:

```
>(element? 'three (quote ((quote three) (quote four) (quote five))))
>,=> #f but i need #t
```

please help.

Comment: in the last line, shouldn't `x` be `xs`?

Comment: it is just a mistake, but even with xs instead x it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

When Scheme encounters a `(quote x)` or it's short form `'x` x is the result unevaluated. Thus `(quote ((quote three) (quote four) (quote five)))` becomes the list `((quote three) (quote four) (quote five))`. I think you meant to pass `(quote (three four five))`, which you could write `'(three four five)` and your procedure would have worked since what you were searching for were the first element.

There is an error that you have an unbound variable making it not work if the searched element is not the first element in lst. `x` which I guess should actually be the bound variable `xs`. I've renamed every `xs` to `x` (since xs usually means a list and here it's a search element)

```
(define (element? x lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) #f) 
        ((eq? x (car lst)) #t) 
        (else (element? x (cdr lst)))))

(element? 'c '(a b c d e f)) ; ==> #t
(element? 'g '(a b c d e f)) ; ==> #f
(element? (quote e) (quote (a b c d e))) ; ==> #t
```

If you really wanted to search for other things than symbols, you should use `equal?` in place of `eq?`, like this:

```
(define (element? x lst) 
  (cond ((null? lst) #f) 
        ((equal? x (car lst)) #t) 
        (else (element? x (cdr lst)))))

(element? '(hello dolly) '((hello paul) (hello dolly) (hello todd))) ; ==> #t
```

Comment: yes, it work correctly with form like  >(element? 'one '(one two three)) but it is not working with  >(quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three))) in place of  >'(one two three))

Comment: `(quote (one two three))` is the same as `'(one two three)`. `(quote ((quote one) (quote two) (quote three)))` is the same as `'((quote one) (quote two) (quote three))` but quote in this last list is just a symbol like hello in `(hello dolly)` and nothing special. You only need one quote for one expression to quote it, not one for each element.

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme there really isn't a concept of 'words' - you've got symbols or strings.  From what you've written your are looking to find symbols.  Your code has a number of simple errors, here is a simple version:

```
(define (element? xs lst)
  (and (not (null? lst))
       (or (eq? xs (car lst))
           (element? xs (cdr lst)))))


> (element? 'three (list 'three 'four 'five))
#t
```

Note: Anytime you see `cond` returning values of `#t` or `#f` you might prefer rewriting in terms of `and` and `or`

Comment: Why should one prefer and/or to cond?

Comment: but it is not working with : **(element? 'three (quote ((quote three) (quote four) (quote five))))** @GoZoner

Comment: Use: `(element? 'three (list (quote three) (quote four) (quote five)))`  If satisfied, please provide a 'check mark' and 'up vote' (when able).

Answer (score -1):

`eq?` tests if two objects are the same location in memory.  It doesn't actually compare values.  If you construct identical strings at two different memory locations, `eq?` returns `false`.  Use `string=` instead.

I wanted to show some example code but Scheme is aggressively interning strings and I can't get two separately allocated identical strings to exist...

[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941817/difference-between-eq-and-in-scheme)

Comment: Symbols, such as `three` are comparable with `eq?`. The OP's problem is that the _symbol_ `three` isn't `eq?` to the _list_ `(quote three)`

Comment: @DenGarif I'm not sure whether that comment was directed toward me or japreiss, but [Sylwester's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19350157/1281433) and the comments on it explain how to solve this problem.  Typically, the elements of a list are considered the `car`s of the cells of the list.  So the elements of `((quote one) (quote two))` are the _lists_ `(quote one)` and `(quote two)`.  Two isn't an element of the list.  Sylwester's answer explains how to find an element in a _tree_ of cons cells; and `two` _is_  an element in the tree `((quote one) (quote two))`.